# Detailed Explanation On How To Setup Quotaguard on Django For Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have gone through the django documentation and quotaguard documentation, but my application still does respond after I put the IP addresses on block.io.

I would like a detailed guide on how to setup quotaguard on heroku

Answer (score 0):

Use python requests library and route api calls using QuotaGuard